# Referencing table name (dynamically) as a column in bigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I think the answer uses Union but I'm having a hard time since I would like to query table names dynamically. At present I have:

```
SELECT
  id,
  created_on,
  operation,
  property_type,
  place_with_parent_names,
  floor,
  rooms,
  expenses,
  price_aprox_local_currency,
  description,
  title
FROM
  `properati-data-public.properties_mx.properties_sell_20*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1501'
  AND '1810'
```

I was trying to add tableName or something like that in the select section, but I couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add below to SELECT Statement

```
CONCAT('properties_sell_20', _TABLE_SUFFIX) table_name
```